# Android 4.0.3. String font color not work

Tags: android

Android 4.0.3

My strings.xml

```
<string name="contacts"><font color="#00FFFF">+</font> Contacts</string>
```

This work fine on Android 4.3+. Set text color = **00FFFF** (cyan)

But on Android 4.0.3 it's not work (not set color).

Comment: Did you parse it with HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `android:textColor=#00FFFF` in XML file, `"view".setTextColor(0xFF00FFFF)` in Java class or use `<font fgcolor="#00FFFF">`

Comment: This work: <string name="contacts"><font fgcolor="#FF00FFFF">+</font> Contacts</string>

Comment: This work on all Android 4.0+ AND all languages:
<string name="congratulations">Hello, how <font color="cyan" fgcolor="#FF00FFFF">do you</font> do</string>